# Two congruent regular tetrahedrons are glued together by their bases. Count the ways to paint the faces of the resulting solid with $7$ colors.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Two congruent regular tetrahedrons are glued together by their bases. In how many geometrically different ways (we consider only rotations) the faces of the resulting solid can be painted (each with one color), having at $7$ colors available?

---

As I understand it - we have such solid. I will look from this side:

[image] [image]

Therefore our group of rotations consists of:

$A1$)

[image]

- $1 \times$ axis $A1$ rotated by $120^{\circ}$: $[1,4] \to [2,5] + [2,5] \to [3,6] + [3,6]  \to [1,4]$, cycles: $x_3^2$, constant points: $7^2$ (upper half in one of $7$ colors, lower half in one of $7$ colors)
- $1  \times$ axis $A1$ rotated by $240^{\circ}$: $[1,4] \to [3,6] + [3,6] \to [2,5] + [2,5] \to [1,4]$, cycles: $x_3^2$, constant points: $7^2$ (upper half in one of $7$ colors, lower half in one of $7$ colors)
- identity ($1 \times$ axis $A1$ rotated by $360^{\circ}$): $[1,4] \to [1,4] + [2,5] \to [2,5] + [3,6] \to [3,6]$, cycles: $x_1^6$, constant points: $7^6$ (every face in every color)

$A2$)

[image]

- $1 \times$ axis $A2$ rotated by $180^{\circ}$: $[1,4] \to [5,2] + [2,5] \to [4,1] + [3,6] \to [6,3]$, cycles: $x_2^3$, constant points: $7^3$ ($3$ pairs of faces in one of $7$ colors)

$A3$)

[image]

- $1 \times$ axis $A3$ rotated by $180^{\circ}$: $[1,4] \to [6,3] + [2,5] \to [5,2] + [3,6] \to [4,1]$, cycles: $x_2^3$, constant points: $7^3$ ($3$ pairs of faces in one of $7$ colors)

$A4$)

[image]

- $1 \times$ axis $A3$ rotated by $180^{\circ}$: $[1,4] \to [4,1] + [2,5] \to [6,3] + [3,6] \to [5,2]$, cycles: $x_2^3$, constant points: $7^3$ ($3$ pairs of faces in one of $7$ colors)

Therefore I would say that the number of different ways the walls of the resulting solid can be painted is equal to:

$$\frac{1}{6} \left(7^2 + 7^2 + 7^6 + 7^3 + 7^3 + 7^3 \right) = \frac{1}{6} \left(49 + 49 + 343 \cdot 343 + 343 \cdot 3  \right) = 19796$$

Does it look correct?

Comment: Your final result has $x_3$ instead of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell that it's not correct because the final answer $$\frac{1}{6} \left(2^7 + 2^7 + 6^7 + 3^7 + 3^7 + 3^7 \right)$$ is not an integer.

If you can choose from $7$ colors to paint the upper half and from $7$ colors to paint the lower half, you can paint the whole polyhedron in $7\times 7 =7^2$ ways, not $2^7$, and you made the same mistake in the other cases.

Comment: Thank you for help! I edited my original question. Now I get an integer. Is that correct? @jjagmath

Comment: @thefool Almost. You need to check your calculations at the end.

Comment: I checked a couple of times and I don't any error @jjagmath

Comment: @thefool How die you calculate $7^6$?

Comment: Yeah, you were right. I edited my post the 2nd time. Thank you @jjagmath