# In how many different ways the vertices of a tree can be colored using $3$ colors? I need to verify my answer

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees, coloring

Let $T = (V, E)$ be a tree with a set of vertices $V = [7]$ and a set of edges:

$$E = \{1, 2 \}, \{1, 3 \}, \{1, 4 \}, \{2, 5 \}, \{3, 6 \}, \{4, 7 \}$$

In how many significantly different ways (with respect to the group of automorphisms of a graph $T$) the vertices of a tree $T$ can be colored using three colors?

*Coloring here means any function that assigns colors to the vertices from the three-element set

*Bijection $g : V \xrightarrow[1-1]{on} V$ is an automorphism of the graph $T$ if for any vertices $v, w \in V$ we have:
$$\{v, w \} \in E \iff \{g(v), g(w) \} \in E$$

**Hint: start by justifying that if $g : V \xrightarrow[1-1]{on} V$ is an automorphism graph $T$, then for every $v \in V$ we have: $d(v) = d(g(v))$.

---

As I understand that, we have such a tree:

[image]

The definition of coloring is pretty straightforward: we just color every vertice in one of $3$ colors.

I don't know how to justify the hint, but I know that the definition of automorphism with added hint means that every tree of the same 'structure' with different combination of vertices (labels of the vertices) is considered the same as long as we preserve the degrees of vertices. Therefore we can only juggle the $3$ (whole) arms of a tree: $\{ 2,5 \} , \{ 3,6 \} , \{ 4,7 \}$.

Therefore we can use Burnside's Lemma.

We can change those arms in one of $3$ ways (I enumerate the $3$ arms with numbers pointing to their position from the RHS):

Shift to the right / left (changing places of all $3$ arms):

- $1$ step in right direction ($= 2$ steps in in left direction): $[1,2,3] \to [3,1,2] + [3,1,2] \to [2,3,1] + [2,3,1] \to [1,2,3]$, cycles: $x_3$, constant points: $3 \cdot 3^2$ (we choose one color for vertex $1$, then each arm has to be in the same colors)
- $2$ steps in right direction ($= 1$ step in in left direction): $[1,2,3] \to [2,3,1] + [2,3,1] \to [3,1,2] + [3,1,2] \to [1,2,3]$, cycles: $x_3$, constant points: $3 \cdot 3^2$ (we choose one color for vertex $1$, then each arm has to be in the same colors)
- $3$ steps in right direction ($= 3$ steps in in left direction): $[1,2,3] \to [1,2,3]$ (identity), cycles: $x_3$, constant points: $3 \cdot 3^6$ (we choose one color for vertex $1$, then each arm can have every combination of colors)

Swaps in pairs:

- first place with second place: $[1,2,3] \to [2,1,3] + [2,1,3] \to [1,2,3]$, cycles: $x_2$, constant points: $3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 3^2$ (we choose one color for vertex $1$, then we choose the colors for the arm that stays in place, then for the arms that swap their places)
- first place with third place: $[1,2,3] \to [3,2,1] + [3,2,1] \to [1,2,3]$, cycles: $x_2$, constant points: $3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 3^2$ (we choose one color for vertex $1$, then we choose the colors for the arm that stays in place, then for the arms that swap their places)
- second place with third place: $[1,2,3] \to [1,3,2],+ [1,3,2] \to [1,2,3]$, cycles: $x_2$, constant points: $3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 3^2$ (we choose one color for vertex $1$, then we choose the colors for the arm that stays in place, then for the arms that swap their places)

At the end we get:

$$\frac{1}{6} \left( 3 \cdot 3^2 + 3 \cdot 3^2 + 3 \cdot 3^6 + 3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 3^2 + 3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 3^2 + 3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 3^2 \right) = \frac{1}{6} \left( 3^3 + 3^3 + 3^7 + 3^5 + 3^5 + 3^5 \right) = \frac{1}{6} \left( 27 + 27 + 2187 + 243 + 243 + 243 \right) = 495$$

Is that correct? How to justify the hint?

Comment: "Automorphism" isn't any old relabeling of vertices; it has to preserve adjacencies. The hint says that an automorphism must preserve degrees. So, e.g., since 1 is the only vertex of degree three, every automorphism must take 1 to 1. Another example: no automorphism can take 4 to 5, since 4 has degree two while 5 has degree one. Also, if an automorphism takes 2 to 3, then it must take 5, which is adjacent to 2, to 6, which is adjacent to 3.

Comment: So I can only juggle the 3 (whole) arms of a tree: $ \{ 2, 5 \}, \{ 3, 6 \}, \{ 4, 7 \}$ ? Therefore there are only: $\frac{3^7}{3!}$ ways to color the graph. We choose color for every vertice and then "delete" the possible $6$ permutations of those $3$ "arms".

Comment: $3^7/3!$ isn't an integer, so it's a bit trickier than that. Some of those $3^7$ colorings have more symmetries than others. You have to look at three cases: all three arms are colored differently, all three arms are colored identically, and two arms are colored the same, one differently. Or, you can look up "Burnside's Lemma" and apply it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think that Burnside's Lemma can be applied here, That's interesting! I used the lema here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753521/two-congruent-regular-tetrahedrons-are-glued-together-by-their-bases-count-the to color faces of a solid. Out there I tried to find the axis of possible rotations, to get all cycles and their constant points. How is that similar to that problem? @GerryMyerson

Comment: Burnside's Lemma applies whenever you have a group acting on a set. In this case, the group of automorphisms acting on the graph.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Is that correct right now? $495$ seems a bit much.

Comment: $495$ is what I got.