# How many paths of length $n$ with given beginning and end are there in the graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Given a graph $G = (V, E)$, with a set of vertices: $V = \mathcal{P}( \{1, 2, 3 \})$
and a set of edges:

$$E = \{ \{A, B \} : A, B \subseteq \{1, 2, 3 \} \wedge |A \bigtriangleup B| = 1 \}$$

*where:

- $A \bigtriangleup B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$ is the symmetric difference of sets $A$ and $B$
- $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is a set of all subsets of $X$

How many paths $(A_0, A_1, ... A_n)$ of length $n \geq 3$ are there in the graph $G$ with a beginning at vertex $A_0 = \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$ and an end at vertex $A_n = \emptyset$ (all vertices, including the end vertex, may repeat)?

---

As I understand it - we have vertices $8$ vertices, those are: { {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1}, {2}, {3}, { } }.

We have $12$ edges and those are:

- $\{1, 2, 3\} - \{1, 2\}$,
- $\{1, 2, 3\} - \{1, 3\}$,
- $\{1, 2, 3\} - \{2, 3\}$,
- $\{1, 2 \} - \{1 \}$,
- $\{1, 2 \} - \{2 \}$,
- $\{1, 3 \} - \{1 \}$,
- $\{1, 3 \} - \{3 \}$,
- $\{2, 3 \} - \{2 \}$,
- $\{2, 3 \} - \{3 \}$,
- $\{1 \} - \{ \}$,
- $\{2 \} - \{ \}$,
- $\{3 \} - \{ \}$.

The graph should therefore look like that:

[image]

The paths that I see working for $n = 3$ are:

- $\{1, 2, 3\} - \{1, 3\} - \{ 3 \} - \{ \}$,
- $\{1, 2, 3\} - \{1, 3\} - \{ 1 \} - \{ \}$,
- $\{1, 2, 3\} - \{2, 3\} - \{ 3 \} - \{ \}$,
- $\{1, 2, 3\} - \{2, 3\} - \{ 2 \} - \{ \}$,
- $\{1, 2, 3\} - \{1, 2\} - \{ 1 \} - \{ \}$,
- $\{1, 2, 3\} - \{1, 2\} - \{ 2 \} - \{ \}$,

There are $6$ of them.

Hovever, I don't see any clever way to count them for a chosen $n$.

---

Edit:

The adjacency matrix of that graph looks like that:

the rows / columns:

1. $\{1, 2, 3\}$
2. $\{1, 2\}$
3. $\{1, 3\}$
4. $\{2, 3\}$
5. $\{1 \}$
6. $\{2 \}$
7. $\{3 \}$
8. $\{ \}$

Therefore the matrix looks like that:

$
M = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

But then it's tp hard to diagonalize...

Comment: Take the adjacency matrix of the graph, raise it to the power $n$, then the entry in the row corresponding to $\{1,2,3\}$ and the column corresponding to $\{\}$ is the number of paths of length $n$. To get a general formula, you'll need the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the adjacency matrix. Although, it occurs to me that the graph is just the edges of a cube, the relevant vertices are at opposite ends of a body diameter of the cube, so maybe the situation is so symmetrical that there's an easier way to get answers.

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A054880

Comment: How about that? https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-number-of-paths-possible-from-A-to-B @GerryMyerson

Comment: The only difference is that we choose one of $3$ ways, as we can go back (vertices may repeat).

Comment: Also, could you have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753606/in-how-many-different-ways-with-respect-to-the-group-of-automorphisms-of-a-grap? I have no idea how to move with this one.

Comment: I can't tell from what I see at that link, just what question is being answered there. But being able to repeat vertices makes a big difference.

Comment: No, never mind. It will not work (the idea from quora).

Comment: I left a comment at that other question of yours.

Comment: Thank you. I will check that in a minute. About that question and adjacency matrix of the graph - I don't see any pattern while calculating the number in in the row corresponding to $\{ 1,2,3 \}$ and the column corresponding to $\{ \}$. I get: $4, 4, 36, 52, 308$. I think that for such a matrix that I get, it's is too complicated to calculate eigenqalues with just pen and paper. Therefore I still have no idea hos to do that.

Comment: You must have set up the matrix incorrectly, or goofed while multiplying. Note that there are no paths of even length from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{\}$; the graph is bipartite, every edge joins a set with an even number of elements to a set with an odd number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is
$$ \frac{3^n-3}{4} $$
for odd $n$, and zero for even $n$.

Since this is a small, symmetric graph, there are many ways to come about this answer. You can diagonalize the $8 \times 8$ adjacency matrix and read off the appropriate values. If that's too big of a matrix to diagonalize, you could instead look at the following system of recurrences:
$$ a_3(n) = 3a_2(n-1) $$
$$ a_2(n) = a_3(n-1)+2a_1(n-1) $$
$$ a_1(n) = 2a_2(n-1)+a_0(n-1) $$
$$ a_0(n) = 3a_1(n-1) $$
where $a_i(n)$ is the number of walks of length $n$ from an $i$-element set to $\emptyset$. This only requires you to diagonalize a $4 \times 4$ matrix. This could be simplified even further to
$$ a_3(n) = 3a_3(n-2) + 6a_1(n-2) $$
$$ a_1(n) = 2a_3(n-2) + 7a_1(n-2) $$
which only requires diagonalizing a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

My favorite way, which requires the least work if you know about generating functions, is the following transformation. Note that each walk can be described by a sequence of $1$s, $2$s, and $3$s, where reading the sequence tells us to add/remove that digit from our current position in the walk. Thus we want to count the number of sequences of length $n$ of $1$s, $2$s, and $3$s with an odd number of $1$s, an odd number of $2$s, and an odd number of $3$s. One way to do this is with exponential generating functions: the answer is
$$ \left[\frac{x^n}{n!}\right] \left( \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + \cdots \right)^3 = \left[\frac{x^n}{n!}\right] \left( \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2} \right)^3 = \left[\frac{x^n}{n!}\right] \frac{e^{3x}-3e^{x}+3e^{-x}-e^{-3x}}{8} $$
$$ = \frac{(3)^n - 3(1)^n + 3(-1)^n - (-3)^n}{8} ,$$
which simplifies as stated at the beginning of this answer. This method also easily generalizes to higher dimensional cubes.

Comment: Ohh, I get it now. Those are $2$ independent ways of solving the problem. At first I didn't understand how you went from diagonalizing $2 \times 2$ metrix to generating functions.

Comment: How did you get the last equation? @BobKrueger

Comment: $(3^n-2)/4$ isn't an integer.

Comment: Also, you can go one step further and use the two recurrences relating $a_1$ and $a_3$ to get $a_3(n)=10a_3(n-2)-9a_3(n-4)$. The characteristic polynomial $x^4-10x^2+9$ factors as $(x+1)(x-1)(x+3)(x-3)$, and away we go.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It's a typo, should be $(3^n-3)/4$.

Comment: @BobKrueger how did you get the last equation? Could you explain?

Comment: @thefool the equation is just Taylor series and algebra. If you are wondering how I got the first expression, this is an easy exercise with EGFs, very similar to the problem you would solve with OGFs (number of multisets of $n$ elements with an odd number of 1's, 2's, and 3's), but since order matters, we use EGFs. If you don't know how to solve the OGF problem, I suggest taking some time to read about generating functions.